# use of recursive function in while loop is going to infinite loop even though decrementing the count value

Tags: java, recursion, while-loop

In order to not to iterate over the infinite loop I am decrementing the count variable inside the while even though it is going to infinite loop when using the recursive function.

```
public class RFibonocci{
    static int n1=0,n2=1,count;
    public RFibonocci(){
        System.out.println("Enter the fibo series:");
        Scanner scr=new Scanner(System.in);
        count=scr.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Series is:");
        System.out.println(n1+"\n"+n2);
        fibo(count-2);
    }
    public static void fibo(int count){
        while(count>0){
            int n3=n1+n2;
            System.out.println(n3);
            n1=n2;
            n2=n3;
            count-=1;
            fibo(count);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String...args){
        new RFibonocci();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not infinite. Just very very very long.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Which 'count` value causes it to run to infinity ?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would change the initial query to the user to "Enter the number of Fibonacci terms to calculate," or something similar.

I would also consider removing the while statement and inserting an if statement for the base-case of the fibo() recursion.

Including a while statement inside the fibo() function creates problems. Not only is the fibo() function being called within the while loop, but the while loop will continue to run after the internal fibo() returns.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to have the `while` loop *and* recurse.  (It looks like it just keeps going because the calls share state through global variables.  Don't do that: as you can see, it makes it hard to debug.)